# Passing data from redirect in Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

We are using Spring 2.5.x and we are doing this: Posting a form, responding to this in the controller method where we generate some data. Now, at the end we are doing a redirect to another page. We need to access the data generated in the post request handler method.

**From the post handler, declared to return a ModelAndView:**

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("myKey", "someValue");
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/my/view", true, true, false), map);

return mav;
```

In the get method handler we want to access these data and use them in the view for this method. How do we access these values? The modelmap that I inject to this method is empty. And only null values are shown in the view if I try to use `${myKey}`

We are using Spring 2.5.x, so I can't use `RequestAttributes` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`FlashMap`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FlashMap.html) which you would get with [`RequestContextUtils`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestContextUtils.html). was added in Spring 3.1. As far as I know, you'll therefore need to implement your own flash attributes mechanism. You can use a servlet `Filter` as explained in [this blog post](https://www.google.ca/search?q=flash%20attributes%20servlet&oq=flash%20attributes%20servlet&aqs=chrome..69i57.2848j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Or, very basically, add stuff to the `HttpSession` and clear them in a future request.

Comment: *We are using Spring 2.5.x* looks like you should address this first.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Because OP is on 2.5, they don't have a choice but to implement their own flash attribute mechanism, afaik.

Comment: Yep. I've post an example in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Save the map data in session scope before executing your redirect. Then in your page, consume the data from the map using JSTL. At the bottom of your page, remove this map from session scope using `<c:remove>`.

In your java class:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("myKey", "someValue");
session.addAttribute("myMap", map);
//the rest of your logic...
```

In your JSP/JSTL code:

```html
Map.myKey value: ${map.myKey}
<!-- at the bottom of the JSP, remove the variable from session -->
<c:remove var="myMap" scope="session" />
```

Comment: @LuckyLuke you have no other option. By the way, a FlashMap (or flash scope) behaves similar.

Comment: Yes, but you don't do that stuff in the JSP. I like the approach by using a filter instead.

Comment: @LuckyLuke well, you have the options, it is your choice now.